# Restful Web service - specifications

Tags: web-services, rest

what is meant by specifications for Restful web service.
I am new to Restful web services and I created a simple Rest web service with a 'Get' method/operation. The web service was created using jersey . I am asked for the specification for this web service and I am not sure what should be the correct answer.

Comment: I think you should visit [this site](http://restpatterns.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It means you need to describe what calls are available and what type of objects they can receive or return. For some examples, have a look at the API documentation of major websites like the [Twitter API Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api), Facebook Graph API, etc.